# Access outlook.com calendar using the software davmail

Tags: calendar, caldav, outlook.com

Using a mobile phone, it is easy to connect to an outlook.com account using `s.outlook.com` as server - as specified by microsoft [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app). I think access should be possible using the software [davmail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net) in a similar way, thus enabling users to access their online calendars via thunderbird/lightning.

What is the URL that davmail needs for this? Shouldn't it simply be a reformatted version of the address given above? NB: The combinations given at the davmail project's website I tried already. Research on the internet did not reveal the solution either. Who can help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

outlook.com exposes only the Exchange ActiveSync (EAS) protocol, while davmail needs the Exchange Web Service (EWS) protocol (or WebDAV).

So, as of today, and until outlook.com exposes EWS, this can not work.